# File access in c++ ubuntu

Tags: c++, mysql, linux

I have developed a program in C++, its task is to read data from MySQL and store the data in files.

First it will read 1000 IDs (column 1, which contains unique values) and store those IDs in file1.
Based on those IDs remaining columns (I had another 7 columns in MySQL) data is stored in another file (assume it is file2).

After reading 22000 IDs then it is giving an error: unable to open file1. Were previously I had  opened it for 22 times with the below code:

```
if( (ptr_eid=fopen (file1, "a") ) == NULL) {
    printf ("\n unable to open %s file",ext_ids_file);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Do you close the file after each successfull write? Maybe your programm blocks the open operation because it has not finished writing it to disk.

Answer (score 0):

From what you say, it rather looks like you open a new file descriptor for every id and then run out of file descriptors.

Please post a minimal code sample that is compilable and reproduces the error on your system.

BTW the description of your approach sounds suboptimal, but it might be I understand it wrong. Again, posting the code would help.